# Q. Is there a guaranteed max time limit for a Cloud function to execute? considering the occasional cold starts

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I'm using Google dialogflow to make a Whatsapp Chatbot for a retail store. I'm using cloud functions to carry out certain operations such as create orders, fetch available products, which are common between other endpoints such as websites and apps.

As cloud functions undergo cold starts, sometimes the cloud functions take long to respond and dialogflow fails in giving a response as it has a max response time of 5 seconds.

Is there any upper limit on the time a cloud function can take to execute? If not, how do i handle this issue in dialogflow.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout),

> Function execution time is limited by the **timeout** duration, which you
> can specify at function deployment time. By default, a function times
> out after **1 minute**, but you can extend this period up to **9 minutes**.