# How to schedule longer python scripts in GCP without cloud functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I have a script that downloads larger amounts of data from an API. The script takes around two hours to run. I would like to run the script on GCP and schedule it to run once a week on Sundays, so that we have the newest data in our SQL database (also on GCP) by the next day.

I am aware of cronjobs, but would not like to run an entire server just for this single script. I have taken a look at cloud functions and cloud scheduler, but because the script takes so long to execute I cannot run it on cloud functions as the maximum execution time is 9 minutes ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046366/q-is-there-a-guaranteed-max-time-limit-for-a-cloud-function-to-execute-conside#:%7E:text=Function%20execution%20time%20is%20limited,period%20up%20to%209%20minutes.)). Is there any other way how I could schedule the python script to run?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For running a script more than 1h, you need to use a Compute Engine. (Cloud Run can live only 1h).

However, you can use Cloud Scheduler. Here how to do

- Create a cloud scheduler with the frequency that you want

  - On this scheduler, use the [Compute Engine Start API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start)
  - In the advanced part, select a service account (create one or reuse one) which have the right to start a VM instance
  - Select OAuth token as authentication mode (not OIDC)
- Create a compute engine (that you will start with the Cloud Scheduler)

  - Add a startup script that trigger your long job
  - At the end on the script, add a line to shutdown the VM (with Gcloud for example)

*Note: the startup script is run as ROOT user. Take care of the default home directory and the permission of the created files*.